# Static equilibrium in an accelerated frame of reference

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, torque, statics

[image: Figure 1]

> TL;DR : I'm trying to resolve an exercice of static equilibrium in an
> accelerated frame of reference but I do not have the same answer as
> the correction for the rotation equilibrium.

We have an homogeous beam of constant section, of mass $M$ and length $L$. The beam is put against a wall. The contact is done without friction. The other part of the beam is laid down against the ground with a dry friction coefficient $f_s^{A}$.

On the other hand, we have a small mass $m$ put on the beam in a point $D$ at a distance $x = \lambda L$. This mass is at the equilibrium because of a dry friction coefficient $f_s^{D}$

Eventually, the whole system is disposed on the horizontal floor of a train carriage.
This train carriage as a constant acceleration $\vec{A}$ in the $\hat{I}_1$ direction.

We consider the orthonormal direct basis {$\hat{I}_1, \hat{I}_2, \hat{I}_3$} as seen on the figure above.

#### Summary of forces :

a) small mass $m$ :

> Weight of the mass : $m\vec{g} = -mg \hat{I}_3$
>
> Reaction of the beam : $\vec{R}_D = \vec{F}_f^{(D)} + \vec{N}_D$
>
> Normal to the beam : $\vec{N}_D = N_D cos(\alpha) \hat{I}_1 + N_D sin(\alpha) \hat{I}_3$
>
> Friction of the mass : $\vec{F}_f{(D)} = F_f^{(D)} cos(\alpha) \hat{I}_3 - F_f^{(D)} sin(\alpha) \hat{I}_1$ \

b) beam of mass $M$ :

> Weight of the beam : $-Mg \hat{I}_3$
>
> Normal to the wall : $N_B = N_B \hat{I}_1$
>
> Reaction of the ground : $R_A = F_f^{(A)} + N_A$
>
> Normal to the ground : $N_A = N_A \hat{I} 3$
>
> Friction of the beam : $\vec{F}_f{(A)} = - F_f^{(A)} \hat{I}_1 $

#### Static equilibrium :

Because we are in an accelerated frame of reference, we have to take into account of the force of inertia given by : $\vec{F}_{iner} = -M\vec{A} = -MA \hat{I}_1$

a) small mass :
\begin{align}
    mg &= N_D sin(\alpha) + F_f^{(D)} cos(\alpha) \\
    mA &= N_D cos(\alpha) - F_f^{(D)} sin(\alpha)
\end{align}

b) beam :

\begin{align}
    N_A &= Mg - F_f^{(D)} cos(\alpha) - N_D sin(\alpha) \\
    N_B &= F_f^{(A)} - F_f^{(D)}sin(\alpha) + N_D cos(\alpha) + MA
\end{align}

So :
\begin{align}
    N_A &= Mg - F_f^{(D)} cos(\alpha) - N_D sin(\alpha) \\
        &= Mg - mg \\
        &= (M + m)g
\end{align}

\begin{align}
    N_B &= F_f^{(A)} - F_f^{(D)}sin(\alpha) + N_D cos(\alpha) + MA \\ 
        &= F_f^{(A)} + mA + MA \\ 
        &= F_f^{(A)} + (m + M)A
\end{align}

#### The problem :

For the rotation equilibrium I get :

\begin{equation}
    L cos(\alpha) N_B - \frac{1}{2}L sin(\alpha) Mg - \lambda L N_D - \lambda L sin(\alpha) mg + \frac{1}{2}L cos(\alpha) MA + \lambda L cos(\alpha) mA
\end{equation}

However, according to the correction I should have :

\begin{equation}
    L cos(\alpha) N_B - \frac{1}{2}L sin(\alpha) Mg - \lambda L N_D - \frac{1}{2}L cos(\alpha) MA
\end{equation}